# Where to find updated listing 'lstpatch.sty'?

Tags: listings

I'm wondering where to find updated patch files, in particular **lstpatch.sty** verson **1.4**?

It seems many packages doesn't come with the file, and my updated TexShop keep asking for the latest version (1.4).

Comment: TeXShop is your editor, so it doesn't really ask for any files.  So what do you mean by saying that TeXShop keeps asking for it?  Is there a message in the log or the console? The `listings` package only loads `lstpatch.sty` *if* the file exists; I don't think there *is* a `lstpatch.sty`. It will only exist for small patches in between versions of the package. If there are no such patches, the file won't be present.

Comment: The latest known `lstpatch.sty` from the original author is of version 1.3b and is available here: http://www.atscire.de/index.php?nav=download&file=lstpatch.sty. But it is already in the current `listings.sty`. this one has the version 1.4 and is available from CTAN.

Comment: @Herbert so with an updated TeXLive you don't need the 1.3b file at all.

Comment: I use the 'lstpatch.sty' as an external file called by 'my.cls' to check bugs. I saw the presence of a similar file in my local directory '/usr/..listings.cfg))(./lstpatch.sty' that comes with TexLive. The message from the _console_ is that _This is a patch for listings 1.3, but you're using version 1.4. Patch is not loaded_. Since TexLive updates regularly, do you think that it loaded the latest file that is now conflicting with my externally called file? I just realised that there is no harm in the conflict as the latest file is chosen.

Comment: @Alan, I tend to agree with Herbert.

Comment: @Herbert....any link to CTAN's listing package?

Comment: @BrettHarry Um, I think Herbert and I are agreeing.  With the current version of `listings` (which, since you're using a Mac I assume you have as part of the MacTeX distribution) you don't need `lstpatch.sty` v. 1.3b. If your class file is loading it, it's doing it incorrectly; it should load it with `\InputIfFileExists`, since it is only needed when there are interim patches relative to the current version. (Also, it's not clear why your class files should load it at all, if it's loading `listings`: let `listings` load it.) As for asking for a CTAN link, are you sure you need help with that?

Comment: @Alan: I already said that the current version is 1.4 and that the last patch is included!

Comment: @BrettHarry: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/

Comment: @Herbert, yes; I just thought that mentioning the existence of 1.3b might have made things less clear for BrettHarry.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The `listings` package only loads `lstpatch.sty` if the file exists; it will only exist for small patches in between versions of the package. If there are no such patches, the file won't be present. With the current version of `listings` (1.4 at time of this answer) (which, since you're using a Mac I assume you have as part of the MacTeX distribution) you don't need `lstpatch.sty v. 1.3b`. If your class file is loading it, it's doing it incorrectly; it should load it with `\InputIfFileExists`, since it is only needed when there are interim patches relative to the current version.

(By the way, TeXShop is an editor, so it doesn't really "ask" for any files; it just reports errors or warnings from the latex compilation itself.)